# How do I bookmark various accounts/records ? similar to adding bookmarks to a chatter post

Tags: lightning, page-layout

I visit multiple accounts/records on our salesforce platform daily and wanted a way to be able to bookmark aka create a running list of records I would like to return to at some point. Similar to what we are able to do in chatter.

Answer (score 2):

you can click on star  icon on top right corner then records will be added to your favorites.

[image]